# Node.js: Regular Expression To Delete Entire Line

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

How do I match the entire line starting with MTA: ?

If I use:

```
console.log(result[2].split("Reporting-MTA:"))
```

I will still get the rest of the line, I want to match the entire line starting with MTA:

Thanks

Edit:

I want to match the line so I can read the lines BEFORE and AFTER that entire line. Now, I can only read the lines before and after the string "Reporting-MTA:"

Edit2:

```
2u+in.4eBZWuGLW.HROP9.bB7WHG
content-type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; na-mm-outgoing-6102-bacon.iad6.com

Final-Recipient: rfc822;g
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0 (permanent failure)
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 5.1.2 - Bad destination host 'DNS Hard Error looking up tiagop.fdforg (MX):  NXDomain' (delivery attempts: 0)



/node/server.js:92
                console.log(r[1]);
               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

With this code:

```
console.log(result[2]);
        var r = result[2].match(/(.*)\r\nReporting-MTA\r\n(.*)/)
        console.log(r[1]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input is from a text file then you need to look for the line breaks, so something like 
this...

It aint pretty but..

Test:

http://jsfiddle.net/wBR73/2/

Comment: In that case you need /(.*)\r\nReporting-MTA\r\n(.*)/  see my updated test above

Comment: I've edited the quesiton using that code exactly. Still can't do it :/

Comment: So which parts do you want? IS the source a text file?

Comment: I want the text after the "Reporting-MTA" line. No, not a text file.

Comment: Dve, it works. Can you let me know why is so complicated and why I can´t get the "before" and "after" that line like I would if I matched the entire line?

Comment: Sorry Im still slightly confused by your terminology. that line only appears so because it has line breaks in it (\r\n). By line I guess you mean stream of text?

Comment: Sorry. Yes. I say 'line' as "Reporting-MTA: dns; na-mm-outgoing-6102-bacon.iad6.com" but now I see that I'm wrong. However, can't I split the result[2] in before the "Reporting-MTA..." line and the after? Like I'd do if I split the entire "line"(string).

Comment: Consider the following.. http://jsfiddle.net/wBR73/3/   
You dont even really need to use regex from the sample you gave, but then again I do no know what the rest of the text stream may look like

Comment: please add the code to your answer instead of just linking to it.

Answer (score 3):

**Code:**

```
var re = new RegExp(/((?:[\n\r]|.)*)(Reporting-MTA.*)((?:[\n\r]|.)*)/);
var arrMatches = strText.match(re);
```

**Result:**

```
arrMatches [1]   // Lines before a line Reporting-MTA:..$
arrMatches [2]   // Line started from Reporting-MTA:
arrMatches [3]   // Other lines after a line started from Reporting-MTA:
```

Comment: Never use `(?:[\n\r]|.)*`. There is a built-in `[^]` construct to match any char in ES standard. Or, there are workarounds like `[\s\S]*`, `[\w\W]*` or `[\d\D]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use match to do regular expression match and return an array of results to matches. This regex matches a pattern that starts (`^`) with `MTA:` and is followed by anything (`.`) zero or more times (`*`)...

```
var matches = result[2].match(/^MTA:.*/)
console.log(matches[0])
```

to capture groups within the match you can use brackets...

```
var matches = result[2].match(/^(MTA:)(.*)/)
console.log(matches[0]) // whole matched string
console.log(matches[1]) // first bracketed group - 'MTA:' in this case
console.log(matches[2]) // second bracketed group - the rest of the string in this case
```

Comment: I probably didn't make myself clear. I want to get the text before and after the line which starts with "Reporting-MTA". I believe I have to use split to get before and after that line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to replace the line(s) you don't want

```
var replaced = result[2].replace(/.*Reporting-MTA:.*/gm,'')
console.log(replaced)
```

Comment: I still get the text before that line, I just want the text after.